# Points of convergence

Tags: real-analysis

I can't seem to solve the following :

Let $\left\{f_n(x)\right\}$ be a sequence of nonnegative continuous functions.

Prove that :

S = $\left\{x \in R |\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}f_n(x) < \infty \in \right\}$

is a Borel Set.

I am thinking something along the lines of :
Let $x \in S$, the above sum is finite and therefore converges. So we should prove that  for $x$ there exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that the sum also converges for  all $y < x + \epsilon$. But how? 
Or we can say since the sequence converges therefore it is Cauchy therefore its points get closer and closer to each other but then how does their inverse make an open interval around $x$?

Comment: Your line of solution cannot work: a Borel set isn't necessarily open, it can consist also of isolated points. Take e.g. the functions $f_n(x)=n|x|$.The sum converges pointwise only in $x=0$, so your claim of finding $\epsilon$ such that all $y<x+\epsilon$ belong to the set of convergence cannot be true.

Comment: Actually, I have difficulty with the concept of Borel Set in general. Based on what I have they are sets in a topological space that can be made from union, intersection and complement of open sets, and they form a sigma algebra. So I guess first I should ask how does one go about proving a set is Borel?

Comment: For a stronger result, [see there](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/524821/6179).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $g_m = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i$ is continuous. Further, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \leq N$ if and only if $g_m \leq N$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$. Thus we have the set equality $\{x \in \mathbb{R} : \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \leq N \} = \bigcap \limits_{m=1}^{\infty} g_m^{-1}([0,N])$. Since $g_m$ is continuous, and $[0,N]$ is closed, this set is closed. Since $S = \bigcup \limits_{N=1}^{\infty} \{x \in \mathbb{R} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \leq N \}$, $S$ is $F_\sigma$.

Comment: I see, very nice. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Check that
$$
S = \cup_{k=1}^{\infty} \{x\in \mathbb{R} : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) \leq k\}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_n(x) \leq k \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x) \leq k \quad \forall m \in \mathbb{N}
$$
since the $f_n$'s are non-negative. Let $g_m(x) = \sum_{n=1}^m f_n(x)$, then $g_m$ is continuous, and
$$
S = \bigcup_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \bigcap_{m \in \mathbb{N}} g_m^{-1}(-\infty, k]
$$
Note: This is a good exercise in trying to prove a set is Borel. What you usually try to do is to express the set as a sequence of unions/intersections, until you hit upon an open/closed set.

Comment: In the last equality, shouldn't it start with 0 and not $-\infty$?
$g_m \geq 0$, isn't it?

Comment: Thanks a lot, so I guess you do usually have to find a way to express the set as a union/intersection of open/closed sets.