# Points of Convergence (functions not assumed to be non-negative)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am interested in a modified version of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/498731/points-of-convergence).

Namely, let $\left\{f_n(x)\right\}$ be a sequence of continuous functions on $[a,b]$. 
Prove that :

S = $\left\{x \in [a,b] |\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}f_n(x) < \infty  \right\}$

is a Borel Set.

When the functions are assumed to be non-negative, we have the following solution:

> Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$. For all $m \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $g_m = \sum_{i=1}^m f_i$ is continuous. Further, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \leq N$ if and only if $g_m \leq N$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$. Thus we have the set equality $\{x \in [a,b] : \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x) \leq N \} = \bigcap \limits_{m=1}^{\infty} g_m^{-1}([0,N])$. Since $g_m$ is continuous, and $[0,N]$ is closed, this set is closed. Since $S = \bigcup \limits_{N=1}^{\infty} \{x \in [a,b] : \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x) \leq N \}$, $S$ is $F_\sigma$.

However, assertion that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n \leq N$ if and only if $g_m \leq N$ for all $m \in \mathbb N$ is false when the $f_n$ can be negative.

Answer (score 1):

Convergent series with real entries being series whose partial sums are a Cauchy sequence,
$$
S=\bigcap_{i\geqslant1}\bigcup_{n\geqslant1}\bigcap_{k\geqslant n}\bigcap_{m\geqslant k}\left\{x\in[a,b]\,;\,\left|\sum_{\ell=k}^mf_\ell(x)\right|\leqslant\frac1i\right\}.
$$
This proves that $S$ is a Borel set as soon as each function $f_n$ is Borel measurable for every $n$ large enough.

Comment: I know that a set E is Lebesgue measurable if $\forall \epsilon > 0$ there exists an open set $O \subset E$ such that $m_{*}(E-O) \leq \epsilon$, where $m_{*}$ denotes the outer measure.  I also know a fuction f is Lebesgue measurable if $f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$ is a Lebesgue measurable set for all a.  Could you please explain what you mean by a "Borel measurable" function, as I am unfamiliar with this term?

Comment: Apparently f is "Borel measurable" if $f^{-1}(-\infty,a])$ is a Borel set for all a.  If the sets in your intersection were open, I see how this would show S was a Borel set.  But I don't see how this connects to each $f_n$ being measurable for every $n$ large enough.

Comment: Borel measurable also means that $f^{-1}(B)$ is a Borel set for every Borel set $B$. In particular, $B$ may be open or closed or...