# Fourier series that converges in $L^2$ but not pointwise

Tags: convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

I've read this in my notes

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ be $2\pi$-periodic, and piecewise continuous with jump discontinuities such that $\displaystyle f(a)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(a^+)-f(a^-)}{2}$ .
>
> Then the series $\displaystyle\sum_{|n|\geq0}c_ne^{int}$ converges to $f$ with respect to $L^2$ convergence.
>
> Nevertheless, there need not exist some $x$ such that $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{|n|\geq0}c_ne^{inx}=f(x)$

The last sentence baffles me, how is it possible that the Fourier series converges pointwise **nowhere** ? Can someone give an example ?

I know that stronger hypotheses counter this statement (if one assumes that $f$ is piecewise smooth for example).

Comment: The relevant theorem in Zygmund's "Trigonometric Series", is Theorem 4.1. The statement is: "There exists an $f\in L^1$ such that its Fourier series diverges everywhere."

Comment: For $f\in L^2$ look here : http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm4/fm4127.pdf

Comment: It seems wrong. [Carleson's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleson%27s_theorem) would imply pointwise convergence a.e.. if $f\in L_2$. @Edwin That article gives an example with $f\in L_1$ whose Fourier series  diverges a.e., no?  Simen K's comment gives a reference to the result that there is an $f\in L_1$ whose Fourier series diverges everywhere (also due to Kolmogoroff).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your notes are messed up; maybe you dozed off while the lecturer changed the assumptions on $f$? :) As others said, $f\in L^2$ implies that the Fourier series converges to $f$ a.e., by Carleson's theorem.

The way your statement is set up is also weird. Setting $$\displaystyle f(a)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{f(a^+)-f(a^-)}{2}\tag1$$ at the jump points of a piecewise continuous function has no effect on $L^2$ convergence of Fourier series. Generally, redefining a function on any set of measure zero does nothing in the context of $L^p$ spaces.

The reason one often sees (1) in this subject is an old theorem of Dirichlet: if $f$ has bounded variation and satisfies (1) at every point, then the Fourier series converges to $f$ pointwise. (Strictly speaking, Dirichlet proved this for  functions with a finite number of extrema, since BV was not invented yet.)

Comment: Beyond having full measure, do you know anything about the complexity of the set of points of convergence of the Fourier series of an $L^2$ function? For instance, do you know whether it is Borel?

Comment: @AndresCaicedo The set where it converges [is Borel](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/524821/). The set where it converges to to $f$ need not be Borel, since we can redefine $f$ on a null set. Also, [this answer seems relevant](http://mathoverflow.net/a/49411). :)

Comment: Yes, of course. :-) I meant convergence to $f$. Let me be more explicit. Assume that $f\in L^2\cap L^1_{loc}$, and that for all $x$ we have $f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\int_{(x-h,x+h)}f(t)\,dt/2h$ (so we have fixed the representative of $f$'s equivalence class. We can use some other fixing convention if it helps). I have asked around a bit to some harmonic analysts but they did not know of any information in this regard.

Comment: Excuse the dumb question, but what does it mean for a function to be in $L^2$? Is it piece wise continuous and $\int_0^{2\pi} |f(t)|^2 dt < \infty$?

Comment: @G.T.R http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space

Comment: I don't know measure theory. Please just tell me if the hypotheses on $f$ in my original post imply $f\in L^2$.

Comment: @G.T.R Yes, they do. Every bounded piecewise continuous function on a finite interval is in $L^2$.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Interesting question. I do not know the answer even when $f$ is continuous (which would be the first case to look at, where no issues with choice of representative arise). In general, the world's favorite representative of a locally integrable function seems to be $f(x)=\lim_{h\to0}\int_{(x-h,x+h)}f(t)\,dt/2h$ when the limit exists and $f(x)=0$ when it does not. Known as *precise representative*.

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake while taking notes then.